# Principle of persistence of functional relations for complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

The following expression is valid for real values of the variable and it's also true for complex values of the variable:
$$
\sin^2z+\cos^2z = 1 \quad \forall z\in R, C
$$

However, the following expression isn't exactly the same for $R$ and $C$ variables:
$$
<u,v> = <v,u>\quad \forall v,u\in R
$$
$$
<u,v> = \overline{<v,u>}\quad \forall v,u\in C
$$

**Question:** Can you please explain the principle of persistence of functional relations for complex variables? When can we transfer formulas from a real to a complex domain without changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That principle of persistence relies on the identity theorem: If two holomorphic functions $f,g:U\to \mathbb{C}$ (where $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$) have the same values on a set $T\subseteq U$ which has a limit point in $U$, then they are equal everywhere in $U$.

In particular, if $U$ contains a non-trivial interval of $\mathbb{R}$, the theorem can be applied. In the simplest case, the argument becomes: If $f,g$ are entire functions in $\mathbb{C}$ so that the equation $f(z) = g(z)$ holds for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then it holds for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Your first example is of this type.

For your second example, note that the scalar product is defined differently for real and complex vector spaces, although the restriction of a scalar product on complex numbers to the reals is still a scalar product on the reals.

Defining $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(u,v) = u \bar v$ and $g(u,v) =  uv$, 
we have $f|_{\mathbb{R}^2} = g|_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, but not $f = g$. This is a good example showing that the mentioned identity principle doesn't extend to functions of more than one complex variable.
edit: And also, the complex conjugation is not a holomorphic function!

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

My impression:

Your first example can be formulated as
$$
f(z) = \sin^2 z + \cos^2 z
$$
and 
$$
g(z) = 1
$$
and one infers from
$$
f(z) = g(z) \quad (z \in \mathbb{R})
$$
that
$$
f(z) = g(z) \quad (z \in \mathbb{C})
$$
holds. The requirement is that $f$ and $g$ are entire holomorphic functions of one variable.

However your other examples would involve
$$
f(u,v) = \langle u, v \rangle \\
g(u,v) = \langle v, u \rangle
$$
which are functions of two variables. The underlying proof is likely to not apply here.